# While loops having trouble

Tags: java

I have tried my code like below..

```
public class GuessNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random rand = new Random();

        int number = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

        int guess;

        System.out.println("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
        System.out.println("");

        guess = scan.nextInt();

        while (guess < number) {
            System.out.println("Higher!");
            guess = scan.nextInt();
        }
        while (guess > number) {
            System.out.println("Lower!");
            guess = scan.nextInt();
        }
        while (guess == number) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm having trouble making it ask until the user gets the right number. And at the end for the game to ask if the user wants to play the game  again

Comment: What happens when you step through in a debugger?

Comment: sometimes it lets me guess until i get it right and other times it only lets me guess like 2 or 3 times

Comment: Consider, for example, what happen if the number is 50 and the first guess is 60.

Comment: Don't forget to give credit to this web site when you turn in your assignment.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of loops here

```
while (guess < number) {
    System.out.println("Higher!");
    guess = scan.nextInt();
}
while (guess > number) {
    System.out.println("Lower!");
    guess = scan.nextInt();
}
while (guess == number) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    break;
}
```

is *creative*. It happens to be flawed, but it's very creative. You need something like

```
while (guess != number) {
  System.out.println((guess < number) ? "Higher!" : "Lower!");
  guess = scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Correct!");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need only a single while loop. rearrange your logic in your loop.

```
boolean isRunning = true;

while(isRunning){

guess = scan.nextInt();

if(guess < number){
  System.out.println("Higher!");
}else if(guess > number){
  System.out.println("Lower!");
}else if(guess == number){
  System.out.println("Correct!");
//ask if need another input. (want to continue or not)
 if(not continue){
    break; or isRunning = false;
 }

}


}
```

Comment: ok so can i do while (...) to ask the user if they want to play again or only that if(...)

Comment: in my code snippet the while is doing the checking of the user input if the guess is higher or lower, then if it is correct it will ask if want to continue(check the comment put your code there) and in the if if the user doesnt want to continue break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not quite right. You want one while loop to check each condition and continue asking for a new number while the guess does not equal the number.

```
while (guess != number) {
  if (guess < number)
    System.out.println("Higher!");
  else
    System.out.println("Lower!");
  guess = scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Correct!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
     if(guess < number)       
        System.out.println("Higher!");
     else if(guess > number)
        System.out.println("Lower!");
     else if (guess == number){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
     }
     guess = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: You should include some text with your code answer so that OP knows what you changed and why it works (or why their code didn't work).